# pandas copy value of previous column in cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cell

I have created a df for cash planning: 
columns = months, 
index = items

I would like to put a formula in a row to multiply the value of the previous month and carry this value through until yearend.

I have seen some examples with shift(), but they copy the value only ONCE and I would like to copy it over the entire month range.

```
columns = ['May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
index = ['Current account', 'Customer payments', 'Salaries', 'Balance']
df = pd.DataFrame(index=index,columns=columns)
df = df.fillna(0) 
df.loc['Customer payments','May']= 111111
df.loc['Customer payments','June':'December']=df.loc['Customer payments'].shift()*0.7
df
```

I have tried some other options like:

```
shift(-1)
```

A loop:

```
for i in range(0,5):
    df.loc['Customer payments','June':'December']=df.loc['Customer payments'].shift(-1)*0.7`
```

A column range:

```
df.loc['Customer payments','June':'December'] = df.loc['June':'December'].shift()*0.7`
```

but to no avail

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
col_vals = {'May':[1,1,1,1], 'June': [2,2,2,2], 'July': [3,3,3,3], 'August': [4,4,4,4], 
            'September': [5,5,5,5], 'October': [6,6,6,6], 'November': [7,7,7,7], 
            'December': [8,8,8,8]}
index = ['Current account', 'Customer payments', 'Salaries', 'Balance']
df = pd.DataFrame(col_vals, index=index)
df
```

```
                    May   June  July August September   October   November  December
Current account     1      2     3      4       5          6         7          8
Customer payments   1      2     3      4       5          6         7          8
Salaries            1      2     3      4       5          6         7          8
Balance             1      2     3      4       5          6         7          8
```

To multiply a single row by 0.7*value in May:

```
df.loc['Customer payments', 'June' :] = df.loc['Customer payments', 'May']*0.7
df
```

```
                    May   June  July August September   October   November  December
Current account     1      2     3      4       5          6         7          8
Customer payments   1     0.7   0.7    0.7     0.7        0.7       0.7        0.7
Salaries            1      2     3      4       5          6         7          8
Balance             1      2     3      4       5          6         7          8
```

To multiply every column starting from May by 0.7 in a rolling-window fashion:

```
df = df.loc[:, 'May' :].shift(1, axis=1)*0.7
df
```

```
                    May   June  July August September   October   November  December
Current account     NaN    0.7  1.4    2.1    2.8         3.5       4.2         4.9
Customer payments   NaN    0.7  1.4    2.1    2.8         3.5       4.2         4.9
Salaries            NaN    0.7  1.4    2.1    2.8         3.5       4.2         4.9
Balance             NaN    0.7  1.4    2.1    2.8         3.5       4.2         4.9
```

Comment: Yes indeed, this is an option, thanks. I wondered if there is an alternative without Transpose.

Comment: Yes, this copies the value of May through to December. However, I was trying to have this as a "moving" cell value, e.g. May copied to June, June copied to July etc... It looks as this is not supported in PandaDataframes....

Comment: @FMassion I am not sure I completely understand what you are trying to achieve. if you want to multiple every month by the same number in a window, try this maybe: ```df.loc[:, 'May' :].shift(1, axis=1)*0.7```

Comment: This doesn't work because. I get a message 'Incompatible indexer with Series'. I just wand to reproduce what I would do in Excel: I have a row with the values of the row 'Customer payments'. I expect that e.g. in [the column] June the inflow of cash would be 70% of the value of [the column] May and that in July it would be 70% of the value of June etc... Actually, I would add some other values, but I don't want to make the example too complicated.

Comment: @FMassion I think that's exactly what the line in my previous comment does. I have updated my answer with an example.

Comment: I am sorry, but the error remains. Here the complete code, in case there is a misunderstanding: `columns = ['May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
index = ['Current account', 'Customer payments', 'Salaries', 'Balance']
df = pd.DataFrame(index=index,columns=columns)
df = df.fillna(0) 
df.loc['Customer payments','May']= 111111
df.loc['Customer payments', 'June' :] = df.loc[:, 'May' :].shift(1, axis=1)*0.7
df`

Comment: @FMassion  The code you posted in your comment is different from what I wrote Have you tried the code I posed above? It works fine without an error. Your code does not work because you are assigning to the Series ```df.loc['Customer payments', 'June' :]``` (to 1 raw = 'Customer payments') the Daraframe, which is ```df.loc[:, 'May' :]``` 
In the code I wrote: ```df.loc['Customer payments', 'June' :] = df.loc['Customer payments', 'May']*0.7 ``` or ```df = df.loc[:, 'May' :].shift(1, axis=1)*0.7```

Comment: My results are: Option 1: df.loc['Customer payments', 'June' :] = df.loc['Customer payments', 'May']*0.7 --> 
May = 111111.0; June = 77777.7; July = 77777.7; August = 77777.7; September = 77777.7; October = 77777.7; November = 77777.7; December = 77777.7
<br>
Option 2: df = df.loc[:, 'May' :].shift(1, axis=1)*0.7 -->
May = NaN; June = 77777.7; July = 0.0; August = 0.0; September = 0.0; October = 0.0; November = 0.0; December = 0.0; Name: Customer payments, dtype: float64
<br> I would have expected sotmething like this:  111.111 ;  77.778 ;  54.444 ;  38.111